# Problem changing icons in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: icons

I wanna change program icons. I previous versions I just went into /usr/share/applications and changed the icon of what I wanted. In 14.04 I repeat this and it doesn't work. Moreover, if I enter in /usr/share/applications being superuser I see that the picture has been changed, but if I enter without being superuser i see that there is no icon.

What's wrong?

Comment: A few questions; 1) How did you exactly edit the `.desktop` file(s) 2) what was the application? 3) Did you edit it with `sudo` or as root? In the last case it would make sense. 3) An application has no other icon than the one defined in the .desktop file. Is there a possible duplicate .desktop file? 4) Could you paste the `.desktop` file or at least the `Icon=` line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The /usr/share/applications consist of `.desktop` files which are owned by `root`.

Eg :- For gedit, the default text editor.

[image]

Here, the `Icon` field shows the name of the `.png` or `.svg` file present in `/usr/share/icons`

Therefore, to change the application icon, you can either edit the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` to point to a new image by specifying its path or replace the `.png` or `.svg` file in `/usr/share/icons` with the icon image you wish to see.

Once you have done either of the above steps, refresh the icon cache using the command

`gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/<name of icon theme>`

Alternatively, it is easier to use Main Menu or `alacarte` -

1. Install *Main Menu* (package name is alacarte) [alacarte [image: Install alacarte]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alacarte)
2. Open *Main Menu* (alacarte)
3. Click on a program and select *Properties* in the right menu.
4. Click on the icon
5. Browse for your new icon and click *Open*
6. Close your programs properties
7. Close *Main Menu*

[image]

You do not need to reboot to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for me alacarte allowed to choose any icon, but that icon could not be shown. Finally, a **128x128 jpg** worked, and symbolic links in the path are no problem.

(If you use Gnome, alacarte may be invoked as: in the main menu of the desktop, right-click on Applications, and choose "Edit Menus")