# Fix Pale Moon launcher icon

Tags: icons, palemoon

I've installed Pale Moon browser in `/opt` on Ubuntu 14.04.  The icon that is displayed in that directory for the Pale Moon program is a simple grey box which when dragged to the gnome launcher bar appears with a question mark on it.  Of course, it does run the program.

There is the appropriate "pretty" blue icon, `Mozicon128.png` in the path `/opt/palemoon25.1.0/browser/icons/`. Is there a way to replace the box with the question mark on the launcher bar with the `Mozicon128.png` icon?

Comment: It is not odd as it is a software that cannot be found in Ubuntu repositories. Perhaps what you need is a propper .desktop file for the program to appear in the launcher: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles  How did you install Palemoon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem changing icons in ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/551627/problem-changing-icons-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the icon, and then I found [well-maintained repositories](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Astevenpusser&package=palemoon) for Ubuntu (including kubuntu, lubuntu, etc.) <strike>12.04 - 16.04</strike> 14.04 – 18.04 at opensuse. So I followed the instructions to completely de-install Pale Moon, then I added the repository and re-installed with apt-get. For my release of Ubuntu:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/stevenpusser/xUbuntu_14.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/palemoon.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install palemoon
```

Just replace `14.04` with the appropriate release number. *(Note that it's a little 'x' with a capital 'U' because it it doesn't mean 'xubuntu'; the 'x' is a like a wildcard, so it means any Ubuntu.)* Also add the key (with appropriate release number):

```
sudo wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:stevenpusser/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
```

Voila! The icon appears correctly in the launcher, and it is installed no longer in `/opt` but in the way other Ubuntu applications are, and easily updated besides.

Comment: Updated & tweaked the answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Install the browser with the [installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pm4linux/files/pminstaller/) or create a desktop file:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/palemoon.desktop
```

with this content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Pale Moon Web Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=palemoon %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=palemoon
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Internet;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;

[Desktop Action NewWindow]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=palemoon -new-window
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action NewPrivateWindow]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=palemoon -private-window
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Comment: I could not get the installer to work in Ubuntu 14.04.4; it would run until I selected to install Pale  Moon, and then just quit abruptly without installing anything. But I found the repositories and used apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

I did use the Source Forge installer.  To fix the problem I found a PPA and installed it.  Your mileage may vary but if you don't use a PPA you may have similar problems.